# java reverse printing hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a string that I have obtained by printing a Hashmap in Java:

```
String a = "{data={field1={field3=value3}, field2={field4=value4, field5=value5}}}"
```

Is there any function in Java that can parse and convert this string into a Hashmap. For this specific string, this function should return a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`.

Comment: Why have you done this? If you wish to serialize data then `toString` isn't the way.

Comment: I want to test a function and I need to get contents of a variable with type Map from another function and use it to test my own function. When I print this variable, I get a very long string and I want a parser to return this string back to a hashmap, so that I can use it in my test function.

Comment: Why convert it to a `String` at all then?

Comment: I want to have the content of that variable by printing it. Do you think I should call the other function in my test function and get its values? To be more specific, I have function `a` that gets its input from function `b`. I want to just test function `a` w/o dealing w/ function `b`. What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Stub function `b` to return some know values. Verify that `a` behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. It just takes a very long time for function `b` to produce its values. That was the reason I wanted to not call function `b` every time I want to test function `a`.

Comment: That's why you [stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463278/what-is-a-stub) it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Google's guava library has similar parser written. Link to answer : [Convert string representing key-value pairs to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768279/6266958)

Comment: The OP needs _nested_ maps, not just a simple `Map`. This approach won't work. I guess you could expand it to attempt recursive resolution of maps nested as values - but that just sounds like a whole can of worms that no-one should open.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. The docs does show a `Map<String, String>` output. Only choice while using this library is to write a recursive parser on the `value` part of the entry.