# How can I test methods containing Application.Current

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, xamarin.forms

There are few methods which have Application.Current.Properties and `Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync` methods.

So how do I test methods having these two in them? I'm stuck after trying to use Unity container for them but its only working for Properties not `SavePropertiesAsync`.

How can I implement it?

I have implemented it as:

```
public interface IAppProperties { IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } }

public class AppProperty:IAppProperties
{
    public const string AppPropertiesName = "AppProperties";

    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

    public AppProperty(IDictionary<string, object> appProperties)
    {
        Properties = appProperties;
    }
}
```

In App XAML.cs

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer(); 
if (!IsUnitTestCase) 
{ 
    container.RegisterInstance<IDictionary<string, object>>(AppProperty.AppPropertiesName, Application.Current.Properties); 
} 
else 
{ 
    container.RegisterInstance<IDictionary<string, object>>(AppProperty.AppPropertiesName, new Dictionary<string,object>()); 
} 
container.RegisterType<IAppProperties,AppProperty>();
Application.Current.Resources.Add("Unity", container);
```

Comment: You need to Stub the `Application` object. Take a look at [What is a Stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463278/what-is-a-stub). If you need more help, update the question with the testing code that you've tried

Answer (score 2):

If a class depends directly on `Application.Current` then you can't test it. But it looks like you're already on track with depending on an abstraction.

Suppose there are three things you need to be able to do:

- Retrieve a property
- Set a property
- Save all properties

You can define an abstraction that represents those behaviors:

```
public interface IApplicationProperties
{
    object GetProperty(string key);
    void SetProperty(string key, object value);
    Task SavePropertiesAsync();
}
```

Your default implementation could look like this (although there's plenty of room for improvement.)

```
public class ApplicationProperties : IApplicationProperties
{
    private readonly Application _application;

    public ApplicationProperties(Application application)
    {
        _application = application;
    }

    public object GetProperty(string key)
    {
        // or whatever behavior you want when the key is missing
        return _application.Properties.TryGetValue(key, out object result) ? result : null;
    }

    public void SetProperty(string key, object value)
    {
        _application.Properties[key] = value;
    }

    public async Task SavePropertiesAsync()
    {
        await _application.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }
}
```

This class could either depend on `Application.Current` or you could inject the `Application` into it.

This could benefit from better type checking and perhaps limiting/defining what settings can be read and set. But it allows you to both access the behaviors of `Application` through an abstraction while mocking the abstraction for unit tests. You could use `Moq` or just write a simple test double to use in tests.

Here's a tweak to the approach that includes a test double:

```
// base class
public abstract class ApplicationPropertiesBase : IApplicationProperties
{
    protected abstract IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; }

    public object GetProperty(string key)
    {
        return Properties.TryGetValue(key, out object result) ? result : null;
    }

    public void SetProperty(string key, object value)
    {
        Properties[key] = value;
    }

    public abstract Task SavePropertiesAsync();
}

// inject this
public class ApplicationProperties : ApplicationPropertiesBase
{
    private readonly Application _application;

    public ApplicationProperties(Application application)
    {
        _application = application;
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, object> Properties => _application.Properties;

    public override async Task SavePropertiesAsync()
    {
        await _application.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }
}

// use for tests 
public class ApplicationPropertiesTestDouble : ApplicationPropertiesBase
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> properties = 
        new Dictionary<string, object>();

    protected override IDictionary<string, object> Properties => properties;

    public override async Task SavePropertiesAsync()
    { }
}
```