# Expected invocation on Mock once, but was 0 times

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, nunit, moq

I have an interface IVehicle

```
public interface IVehicle
{
        Task<ApiResponse> GetVehicleInfo();
}
```

This is my implementation of the interface

```
public class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    private string m_vehicleId;        
    private VehicleInfoEndPoint m_vEndPoint;

    public Vehicle()
    {

    }
    public Vehicle(string vehicleId, string device, HttpClient client,string Uri)
    {            
        m_vEndPoint = new VehicleInfoEndPoint(device, client, Uri);
    }
    
    public async Task<ApiResponse> GetVehicleInfo()
    {
        await m_vEndPoint.GetVehicleInfoPostAsync();
        return m_vehicleInfoEndPoint.FullResponse;
    }        
}
```

I want to unit test this class. For that I have written the following code.

```
    [Test]
    public void Vehicle_GetVehicleInformation_shouldCall_VehicleInfoEndPoint_GetVehicleInfo()
    {            
        var endPointMock = Mock.Of<IVehicleInfoEndPoint>();
        var result = new ApiResponse();
        var vehicle = new Mock<IVehicle>();

        vehicle.Setup(x => x.GetVehicleInfo()).Returns(Task.FromResult(result));

        var response = vehicle.Object.GetVehicleInfo().Result;
       
        Mock.Get(endPointMock).Verify(x => x.GetVehicleInfo(), Times.Once);
    }
```

My test is failing with the error that

Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times `x=> x.GetVehicleInfo()`

Comment: I've moved the tags from your question title to the tags section of your question. Be aware that [tagging guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) state: _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_ and also explicitly state that title formats such as _"[tag] [tag] [question title] [tag] [tag] [tag]"_ or _"[tag]: [question title]"_ should be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it seems you want to test is that `x.GetVehicleInfoPostAsync()` is called.

Being this the case, you have to define your unit artifacts which are:

- **Vehicle** is your system under test
- **IVehicleInfoEndPoint** is your mock
- You want to assert that calling GetVehicleInfo() calls the mock endpoint

I made this quick example that does what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var endPointMock = Mock.Of<IVehicleInfoEndPoint>();
        var vehicle = new Vehicle(endPointMock);
        // ACT
        var response = await vehicle.GetVehicleInfo();
        // ASSERT
        Mock.Get(endPointMock).Verify(x => x.GetVehicleInfoPostAsync(), Times.Once);
    }
}
public interface IVehicle
{
    Task<ApiResponse> GetVehicleInfo();
}
public class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    private readonly IVehicleInfoEndPoint _endpoint;
    public Vehicle(IVehicleInfoEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        _endpoint = endpoint ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(endpoint));
    }
    public async Task<ApiResponse> GetVehicleInfo()
    {
        await _endpoint.GetVehicleInfoPostAsync();
        return _endpoint.FullResponse;
    }        
}
public interface IVehicleInfoEndPoint 
{
    Task GetVehicleInfoPostAsync();
    ApiResponse FullResponse { get; set; }
}
public class ApiResponse
{
}
```

It helps when you divide your test into 3 parts:

- Arrange
- Act
- Assert

Check this out: [What is a "Stub"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463278/what-is-a-stub)

Also, checkout "The art of unit testing" on Amazon, great book.